# A view about schwarz reflection principle?

Tags: complex-analysis

> definition: a curve $r$ to be an analytic curve if every point of$r$  has an
> open neighborhood $U$ for which there is a conformal map $ζ→ z(ζ)$ of a disk
> $D$ centered on the real line$\Bbb R$ onto $U$, such that the image of $D∩\Bbb R$ coincides with $U∩r$.

We can definition the reflection point $z*$ of $z$ about a analytic curve $r$ by $z^*=z(ζ)$,this is the usual situation if $r$ is  straight line.

> theorem:Let $D$ be a domain that is symmetric with respect to the real
> axis, and let $D^+ = D ∩\{Im(z) > 0\}$. Let f( z) be an analytic function on $D^+$
> such that $Imf(z) → 0$ as $z∈ D^+$ tends to $D∩\Bbb R$ Then $f(z)$ extends to
> be analytic on D, and the extension satisfies
> $f(\bar z) = \overline {f(z)}$, $z∈D$.

If we use the reflection point,then we have$f( z^*) = (f(z))^*$

> definition: an analytic cruve $r∈∂D$ is a free analytic bound cruve  of $D$ if every point of $r$is contained in a disk$ U$ such that $U\setminus r$ has two components, one contained in D and the other disjoint from D.

> Theorem:Let $D$ be a domain, and let $r$ be a free analytic boundary cruve of $D$. Let $f(z)$ be analytic on $D$. If $|f(z)| →1$ as z∈D tends to $r$ then $f(z)$ extends to be analytic in a neighborhood of$r$ and the extension satisfies
> $f(z^*) = 1/ \overline {f(z)}$ in some neighborhood of  $r$.

we know the image of $r$ under $f$ is a unit circle, and the reflection point $z*$ of $z$ about unit circle is $1/\bar z$
then use reflection point we have $f( z^*) = (f(z))^*$

So i think the thesis:

> " if $f(z)$ is analytic on one side of an analytic cruve $r$ and the value tend to another analytic cruve as z tends to $r$, then $f$ can analytically extend across $r$ and satisfied $f( z^*) = (f(z))^*$",

it is ture?I think it is ture,but how to prove it?

Comment: You need that $f$ is continuous on the open plus its boundary curve. Do you need help for your last (true but not ture) statement ? Locally there are two biholomorphisms such that $\phi \circ f \circ \varphi$ satisfies the standard Schwarz reflection

Comment: I want to know my last statement is true or not true

Comment: and how to prove it or Where can I find this proof

Comment: $\phi,\varphi$ come from your definitions..

Comment: reflection map?